# can't find symbol, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, class, object, int, symbols

So basically I am calling a class into my main and then trying to print out the final line at the bottom but it keeps saying that it can't find the symbol for int x and int y.  Im pretty sure I assigned them accordingly to the right console input.  Does anyone know what am i doing wrong.  Im new to java.

```
import java.util.*;

public class mainRational {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner console2 = new Scanner(System.in);        

        System.out.println("Enter a number for the numerator and denominator: ");

        //creates the first class object
        rationalNumbers rational = new rationalNumbers(console.nextInt(), console2.nextInt());

        int x = console.nextInt;
        int y = console2.nextInt;

        System.out.println("Rational Number is: " +x+ "/" +y);
    }
}
```

PUBLIC CLASS

```
public class rationalNumbers {

private int Numerator;
private int Denominator;
private String String;



public rationalNumbers(int Numerator, int Denominator){

    if (Denominator==0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.Numerator=Numerator;
    this.Denominator=Denominator;

}

public void rationalNumber(){

}

public int getDenominator(){
    return Denominator;

}

public int getNumerator(){
    return Numerator;
}

public String toString(){
    return String;
}
```

}

Comment: 1. Why do use two separate Scanner objects to access the same standart input stream? It's not neccessary, you'd bettr use one Scanner.

2. May be you meant somethong like:
int x = rational.x;
int y = rational.y;
?
Because now you read two numbers, store them in rational and never use thar rational. Then you read additional two numbers from console and print them.

3. Conventions are to use Uppercase letter first in classes names

Comment: is it even going to work with 2 scanners ?

Comment: yes it runs and compile with two scanner because in my class is an int numerator and int denominator so best way i know how is to use two separate scanner for each because i need different inputs each time

Comment: just added my class file, it shows the reason why i added two scanner

Answer (score 1):

instead of `console.nextInt` it should be `console.nextInt()`

You are unnecessarily creating two Scanner object
This should make more sense

```
System.out.println("Enter a number for the numerator"); 
int x = console.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter a number for the denominator"); 
int y = console.nextInt();
rationalNumbers rational = new rationalNumbers(x,y); //follow class naming convention
System.out.println("Rational Number is: " +x+ "/" +y);
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. You should take the order of the method calls into consideration. If OP just edits his code according to your answer, he won't get the expected result

Comment: @stealthjong but what is the expected output?

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant.

Comment: i just added my class file, this is why i am using two scanner

Comment: so what is the problem if you do like what I told? btw where is your division logic you are just initializing the fields using constructor

Answer (score 0):

`nextInt()` is a method of your Scanner objects (which has the side effect of blocking until a line is entered). In the call to the constructor of your `rationalNumbers` class, you reference it accordingly, so that's fine. In the definitions of `x` and `y`, you reference a `nextInt` member variable, which doesn't exist. You could call the method again, as in

```
int x = console.nextInt();
int y = console2.nextInt();
```

In this case, the user would have to enter two more numbers. You could do this before constructing the rationalNumbers object, and reuse x and y for your constructor arguments, in order to print the same numbers you passed to the rational object.

By the way, there's no need for two different `Scanner` objects in your example; you could replace every use of `console2` with `console` for the same effect.